# Excel VBA - Replace chart marker with picture

Tags: excel, vba, charts, marker

I would like to replace the markers of a line chart with a picture in VBA.

This is equivalent to:

[image]

I copied/pasted this picture in a sheet of the workbook and called it `picture`.

```
With .ChartObjects("graph").Chart
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStylePicture
    ...
End With
```

What should I use to replace `...` and point to my image?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you would call for the sheet and shape, so either `.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.Shapes(Sheets("").Shapes("picture"))` or `.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.Shapes("picture")` come to mind.

Comment: Nope, none of them works. I have an `Object doesn't support this property or method` error on the lines you provided.

Comment: Sorry those didn't help; was taking a stab... Have you seen [this link about changing data markers](http://www.andypope.info/charts/piedatamarkers.htm)?  Possibly you can do somethign similar where you can copy the image "picture" and paste onto the chart marker value.

Comment: Great, it's working! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Cyril's suggestion](http://www.andypope.info/charts/piedatamarkers.htm) I managed to copy/paste the picture to replace the last point of the serie.
The code is:

```
Sheets("param").Shapes("picture").CopyPicture
With .ChartObjects("graph").Chart
    .Points(.Points.Count).Paste
End With
```

If anybody has a better solution feel free to post it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something on your files system then you can use this:

```
With .ChartObjects("graph").Chart
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStylePicture
    .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.UserPicture "C:\...your path...\pic.png"
End With
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I would like to have the picture embedded in the file so I can send it to someone.